# My Axios Response Interceptor Is Failing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Could you help me to figure this out.

I need to refresh my token on error and retry failed requests..

I have:

```
 axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    return response;
  }, function(error) {
      const originalRequest = error.config;

      if(error.response.status===401 && !originalRequest._retry) {

        originalRequest._retry = true;

        setTimeout(async function() {
          const refreshedHeader = await setHeader()
          console.log('New header: ', refreshedHeader)
          axios.defaults.headers = refreshedHeader
          originalRequest.headers = refreshedHeader
          console.log('Original Request: ', originalRequest)
          return axios(originalRequest)
        }, 2000);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

setHeader() is this:

```
  const setHeader = async () => {
    const token = await refreshToken()
    const header = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    };
    return header
  }
```

The new token is pulled and the header is updated, but the retry fails with 401 still?

Comment: For what reason do you need that timeout?

Comment: The API uses rate limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the timeout. This:

```
return Promise.reject(error);
```

will always return an error before the timeout has done its job.
Try to remove that timeout and set the error function to async.

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    return response;
  }, async function(error) {
      const originalRequest = error.config;

      if (error.response.status===401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const refreshedHeader = await setHeader()
        console.log('New header: ', refreshedHeader)
        axios.defaults.headers = refreshedHeader
        originalRequest.headers = refreshedHeader
        console.log('Original Request: ', originalRequest)
        return axios(originalRequest);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

Else if necessary try something like:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response) {
    return response;
  }, async function(error) {
      await new Promise(function(res) {
        setTimeout(function() {res()}, 2000);
       });

      const originalRequest = error.config;

      if (error.response.status===401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        const refreshedHeader = await setHeader()
        console.log('New header: ', refreshedHeader)
        axios.defaults.headers = refreshedHeader
        originalRequest.headers = refreshedHeader
        console.log('Original Request: ', originalRequest)
        return axios(originalRequest);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

This will block all of the rest for 2 seconds and then resolve or reject it.

Comment: I'll try it without the timeout, I have a feeling it will fail due to rate limiting though. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited a version with a timeout, try to move the return Promise.reject inside the timeout or block the whole thing with the timeout in general.